# json unmarshal uses different datatypes in one list

Tags: json, go

I have this json file:

```
{
   "Path":"",
   "Tables":[
      {
         "name":"testTable",
         "content":{
            "c1":[
               1,
               2,
               3
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

When I parse it into these structs:

```
type Database struct {
    Path   string  `json:"Path"`
    Tables []Table `json:"Tables"`
}
```

```
type Table struct {
    Name    string           `json:"name"`
    Content map[Column][]any `json:"content"`
}
```

(I am working with `any` to store any possible value into the db)

And then Iterate over content and []any to print out the datatypes everything is a float64, as I am expecting, except for the last value, which is an int. The output is this of `c1` is:

```
+1.000000e+000
+2.000000e+000
3
```

Playground example

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
)

type Column string

type Table struct {
    Name    string           `json:"name"`
    Content map[Column][]any `json:"content"`
}

type Database struct {
    Path   string  `json:"Path"`
    Tables []Table `json:"Tables"`
}

func (t *Table) Select(columns ...Column) Table {
    var newTable Table
    newTable.Content = make(map[Column][]any, 0)
    for _, c := range columns {
        if t.Content[c] != nil {
            newTable.Content[c] = t.Content[c]
        }
    }
    return newTable
}

func (d *Database) Get(table string) *Table {
    for _, t := range d.Tables {
        if t.Name == table {
            return &t
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"Path":"","Tables":[{"name":"testTable","content":{"c1":[1,2,3,3],"c2":[2,2,1,1],"c3":[3,3,2,2]}}]}`
    var db Database
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &db); err != nil {
        panic("error")
    }
    t := db.Get("testTable")
    ts := t.Select("c1", "c2")
    for _, v := range ts.Content {

        for _, v2 := range v {
            //println(v2.(int)) - panic
            //println(v2.(float64)) - panic
            switch v2.(type) {
            case int:
                println(v2.(int))
                break
            default:
                println(v2.(float64))
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: JSON doesn't have integers and floats, it only has number. If you don't tell what you want (by using `any`), the `json` package will choose `float64`.

Comment: When then try to cast it using, for example, `v.(float64)` it will give an error: `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is int, not float64`
When I do `v.(int)` it will give this error:  `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is float64, not int` (v being an element in []any)

Comment: You neither showed you you unmarshal the JSON nor how you iterate over it nor how you print the values. If you need help you have to provide a standalone, runnable, minimal example showing the behaviour you do not understand.

Comment: @Volker alright, I'll edit the post. EDIT: I have edited the post with all the code and my main.go file

Comment: 1. This is not runnable, e.g. there is no import for json, and Column is undeclared. 2. It's not standalone (loads stuff from FS). Please provide a **standalone** and **minimal** example showing your problem. Make it runnable in the Playground, then post the code here.

Comment: I posted one. Somehow the output here is always float and the typecasting to float64 always works. On my pc it doesnt work, as stated in the panics above. Weird. Could it be, that there is a difference between using a string and a file?

Comment: If https://go.dev/play/p/VTr2xasBFzZ doesn't reproduce the error then the error is not in that part of the code. Do not use println to debug code.

Comment: @0x3alex : now that you have this playground example, you can copy/paste it in a test.go file on your own pc and run `go run test.go`. Do you also see non float64 elements on your PC ?

Comment: it seems to be gone now. Very weird :S

Answer (score -1):

Try `fmt.Printf("%f",v2)`.